# Javascript - add parameters to a function passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

Here is the behaviour I'm looking for:

```
function one(func){
   func(5);
}

function two(arg1, arg2){
   console.log(arg1);
   console.log(arg2);
}

one(two(3)) //prints 3, 5
```

Can this behaviour or something similar be accomplished in javascript?

Comment: Can't get the purpose of the functions from the code. It'll better if you can explain it in language.

Comment: There is no purpose, these are dumbed down examples to illustrate what I am looking for without unnecessary details

Comment: I think @MrFarberToYou's answer sums up my thought as well.

Comment: That behaviour is impossible as is; you're only passing one argument to `two` yet are immediately trying to log the value of two arguments, at least one of which cannot exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some workaround is possible

```js
function one() {

  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var func = args[0];
  args.splice(0, 1);
  args.push(5);
  func.apply(this, args);
}

function two(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1);
  console.log(arg2);
}

one(two, 3)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can always use the **bind()** function to pass some arguments to your function. It'll create a new function with the first argument - **arg1** - equal to the value of **3** in this example:

```
function one(func){
   func(5);
}

function two(arg1, arg2){
   console.log(arg1);
   console.log(arg2);
}

one(two.bind(null, 3))
```

You can read more about the **bind()** function here: [MDN - Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with your syntax: function `one` is expecting its single argument to be a function.  Then, below, when you invoke it, you are not passing the function `two`, but whatever `two` returns when it's passed a single argument, probably `undefined`.  I don't know what specifically you're trying to accomplish but I'd recommend a little research into [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: if `two(3)` call returns a function then `one` is receiving function as argument.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as `one` expects function as argument `two(3)` should return function.
**this condition is required**
so in order to achieve it your `two` function should be

```
function two(arg1){
    console.log(arg1);
        return function(arg2) {
        console.log(arg2);
    };
}
```

so `two(3)` function call gets passed as argument to `one`
so before assigning value to variable engine executes it. And execution of  `two(3)` call logs `3` to console and returns function

```
   function(arg2) {
      console.log(arg2);
    };
```

and then engine assigns executed value(returned function) to `func` variable.
so `func` parameter of `one` function now looks like

```
func = function(arg2) {
    console.log(arg2);
 };
```

`one` calls `func` with `5` passed in as argument.
so `5` gets logged to console.

Answer (score 0):

```
function one(arg){
   two(arg, 5); // func here is two so it requires two params...
}

function two(arg1, arg2){
   console.log(arg1);
   console.log(arg2);
}

one(3)// one expect function so can't execute function here!
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, the idea is the function one doesn't know what the first argument to be passed is before the function is called

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't specify the parameter in the function or it'll run.  You need to specify the function aka one(two), but that obviously wouldn't work.

However if you dynamically create a function you should be able to accomplish the task like so :

```
function one(func){
   func(5);
}

function two(arg1, arg2){
   console.log(arg1);
   console.log(arg2);
}

one(function(val) { two(3, val) }) //prints 3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

well somehow this things work for me

```js
function one(func){
  console.log("one is running");
  func;
}

function two(args1, args2){
  console.log("two is running");
  console.log("args1 -> " + args1);
  console.log("args2 -> " + args2);
}

//to call it
args1 = 6;
args2 = 12
one(two(args1,args2));
```