# Javascript: Dynamic Function with Parameter

Tags: javascript

This is kind of tricky, but I need to make the large code block below generic.

I have a number of views that follow the same format:  A table full of rows, where each row contains a delete icon.  Each icon has a data-id attribute which is the item's _id in the database.

I am wiring the click action on each icon to where it opens a standard dialog to ask for confirmation.  As you can guess, the "Yes" button of the dialog will have an onclick which calls the desired function with a parameter of the item's _id.  e.g., setting `onclick = deleteContact(fdke75jdsgtd7i)`

Let's say I have 3 tables:  Contacts, Cases and Firms.

I got all the wiring to work for any given table, provided I copy and paste the following code block in every view **with the caveat that I have to use the commented onclick line instead of the generic, uncommented line below it**.

```
let deleteItemAnchors = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-item");

Array.from(deleteItemAnchors).forEach( (item) => {

    item.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Highlight the selected row.
        highlightedTableRow = item.closest("tr");
        highlightedTableRow.classList.add("table-warning");

        // The record's _id is in the data-id attribute.
        let itemId = item.getAttribute("data-id");

        let buttons = [{
            //onclick: () => { removeTableRowHighlight(); deleteContact(itemId); },
            onclick: () => { removeTableRowHighlight(); deleteFunction(itemId); },
            text: "Yes"
        }, {
            onclick: () => { removeTableRowHighlight(); },
            text: "No",
            class: "btn-secondary"
        }];

        let confirmDelete = new CustomDialog("Delete this " + recordType + "?", 'Click "Yes" to delete it.  Press "No" to cancel.', buttons);

    });

});
```

Here is an example of the function called when the button is clicked:

```
function deleteContact(itemId) {
    console.log("You deleted the item with id = " + itemId);
}
```

**Bear in mind, it is only working if the commented onclick line is live, and the generic line right below it is comment out.**

I want to stop recreating the big block of code for every view by moving it to a re-usable function which can be called from each of the 3 views as follows:

```
let deleteFunction = () => { deleteContact(); };  
wireDeleteIcons("Contact", deleteFunction);


let deleteFunction = () => { deleteCase(); };
wireDeleteIcons("Case", deleteFunction);
```

So, I moved the code block to a function called, "wireDeleteIcons," which accepts:

- the record type as a string, and
- the function which does the deleting, like deleteCase() or deleteContact().

From my Contacts view, I am calling:

```
let deleteFunction = () => { deleteContact(); };  
wireDeleteIcons("Contact", deleteFunction);
```

It is all working so far, except for the deleteFunction(itemId) call when the icon is clicked.

If you look back up at the big code block, check out the line below the commented onclick line.

I am trying to add the parameter, itemId, to the function that was passed. On testing, it makes it all the way to my deleteContact() function, **but it doesn't pass in the _id.**  So, my console.log shows, per my deleteContact() function, "You deleted the item with id = undefined"

How can I pass the function generically, and insert the parameter into it from within my generic wireDeleteIcons() function?

Comment: add `console.log(itemId);` after `let itemId = item.getAttribute("data-id");` - what do you see in the console?

Comment: @Igor   I see 5a4292d983e1cd0a6cd35eda. It's type is string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteFunction()` needs to take an argument:

```
let deleteFunction = (id) => deleteContact(id);
```

But you don't really need the `deleteFunction` variable. Just write:

```
wireDeleteIcons("Contact", deleteContact);
wireDeleteIcons("Case", deleteCase);
```

The definition of `wireDeleteIcons` should be something like this:

```
function wireDeleteIcons(tableId, deleteFunction) {
    let deleteItemAnchors = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByClassName("delete-item");

    Array.from(deleteItemAnchors).forEach( (item) => {

        item.addEventListener('click', () => {

            // Highlight the selected row.
            highlightedTableRow = item.closest("tr");
            highlightedTableRow.classList.add("table-warning");

            // The record's _id is in the data-id attribute.
            let itemId = this.getAttribute("data-id");

            let buttons = [{
                onclick: () => { removeTableRowHighlight(); deleteFunction(itemId); },
                text: "Yes"
            }, {
                onclick: () => { removeTableRowHighlight(); },
                text: "No",
                class: "btn-secondary"
            }];

            let confirmDelete = new CustomDialog("Delete this " + recordType + "?", 'Click "Yes" to delete it.  Press "No" to cancel.', buttons);

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to assign the parameter, id, from inside the wireDeleteIcons() function.  It is there where id is known and available.  It is unknown until that point.

Comment: Doesn't it already do `deleteFunction(itemId)` as you show in your first code block?

Comment: It tries to.  My console.log shows that itemId is undefined by the time it hits deleteContact().  Remember, I pass deleteContact() in as a parameter to wireDeleteIcons().  At that point in time, deleteContact() has no parameters.  wireDeleteIcons() receives it as deleteFunction(), again without parameters (it's just a ref to deleteContacts).  I am trying to push a parameter into it at the line you indicate, but the push is not happening with the syntax I am using.

Comment: Keep in mind I am not running the function in wireDeleteIcons().  I am merely trying to attach the function to the button's click.  But I need to add the itemId as a parameter to this "parameter-less" function.

Comment: That should be fine, the binding of `itemId` should be saved in the closure.

Comment: I've added what I think the full code should look like, I think it should work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've tried.  It calls the proper function.  In other words, it knows deleteFunction is actually deleteContact().  But when I click the button, it calls deleteContact(), which is good, but it does **not** send the parameter to it.  This other SO topic seems like it might be in the general direction.  Notice in the first answer it is pushing parameters into the function.  This is not the solution for my problem. but the technique might be similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002334/javascript-add-parameters-to-a-function-passed-as-a-parameter

Comment: For example, I just tried calling wireDeleteIcons("Contact", deleteContact("junk") ).  Now, it has 1 parameter.  On click, the process trickles all the way through to deleteContact("junk").  itemId is completely ignored, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The second argument to `wireDeleteIcons` should just be `deleteContact`, not `deleteContact("junk")`.

Comment: You are the man!  Thanks.  I overlooked the parameter, id,  in the anon function which you showed as follows:  let deleteFunction = (id) => deleteContact(id);