# Add parameters to function prop that already has parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have no idea if this could work, but this is a non-working/naive example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
const myFunction = ({ alpha, beta }) => {
  console.log(alpha)
  console.log(beta)
}

const Parent = () => 
  <div>
    <div>Some content...</div>
    <Child handleClick={() => myFunction({ alpha: 1 })}  />
  </div>

const Child = ({ handleClick }) => 
  <button onClick={ () => handleClick({ beta: 2 })}>Click me</button>
```

**Explanation:**
- I'm refering to the function `myFunction`, sent as a prop with a parameter.
- Eventually when fired, a second parameter should be added to the passed function's

When running the above example code, `myFunction` is only receiving the `alpha` parameter.

Example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wn990p5ln?expanddevtools=1)

Comment: possible method to obtain the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002334/javascript-add-parameters-to-a-function-passed-as-a-parameter

Comment: You could write `(data) => myFunction({ ...data, alpha: 1 })` in the `Parent` component.

Comment: @Tholle Wow, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new object that is a copy of the object you pass in from the `Child` component and add the `a` property to it, and pass that as argument to `myFunction`.

```
<Child handleClick={(data) => myFunction({ ...data, alpha: 1 })} />
```